# In Python + FastAPI, how to access a Gunicorn served website hosted in a VM on Oracle Cloud

Tags: python, oracle, gunicorn, fastapi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a Python + FastAPI website, I use Gunicorn as the server. The website has been running successfully in local environment.

I have created a VM instance with Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle Cloud and installed all needed Python packages.

I also followed [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/flask-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-flask-summary.htm) to setup/enable Internet Access with port 5000 in Step 3 and Updated firewall settings in Step 4

I am not using virtual env.

Now I ssh into the VM and cd into the project root folder where the main.py is and ran this command:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app --timeout 1200 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Here is how it looks like in the command line:

[image]

Here is how the subnet details look like:

[image]

Then when I tried to access the website by this link:

```
subnet05182336.vcn05182336.oraclevcn.com
```

My website is never showing up.

```
Server not Found
```

is displaying on the Tab.

### Update 1

I found that I should use ip address( http://168.138.12.192/) to access my website.

I followed [a new article](https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/connect-your-bot-to-ml-api/set-oracle-linux-instance1.html#GUID-7F675809-EABD-42F9-BA5F-2FEDCF019789) to setup Nginx and now when accessing the IP, I can see the default Nginx website has been set up.

Here is my Ingress Rules:

[image]

How could I somehow make Nginx works with Gunicorn to see my Python website? Or maybe I don't even need Gunicorn any more after installed Nginx?

Comment: not sure why down vote, but it has become a pretty common thing for some lazy users to down vote questions without giving any reasons. Such a poisonous and discouraging behavior for users to come here to ask questions. Hopefully SOF could come out with some ways to ban users down vote questions without giving any reasonable reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please confirm from where are you trying to access the website? The DNS domain name that you have mentioned is only for internal within the OCI use, this cannot be accessed from outside. For that you need to configure Custom DNS zone.

Please try to access the website from a new terminal, connect to your Ubuntu VM with your SSH keys, and then in the command line enter curl localhost:5000. Or, you can connect your browser to the public IP address assigned to your VM: http://<x.x.x.x>:5000.

Comment: hi Anupam, thanks for your reply. yes, I realized that I should use IP to access my website. I also updated my question to provide more information. Please see Update 1. Thanks

Comment: also, I have tried `curl http://localhost:8000` and I can see my Python website code. I now use port 8000